# Android - How to build project by check out Tortoise SVN directories?

Tags: android, svn, shell, repository

I am working on `android` applications which has common `src` and `res`- (`layout` and `values`) content and `drawable` content varies among applications.

I have stored complete Application content as 3 directories in `SVN` Repository.

**1. *Application Common Content***

-> `src` ->(All Java Code - `Class1.java`, `Class2.java`, ....)

-> `res` ->(`values`, `anim`)

**2. *Application1***

-> `src` (`AppClass1.java` to access the `Class1.java` of *Application Common Content*'s `src`)

-> `res` -> (`drawable`, `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-ldpi`, `drawable-mdpi`, `raw`)

-> `AndroidManifest.xml`

**3. *Application2***

-> `src` (`AppClass2.java` to access the `Class1.java` of *Application Common Content*'s `src`)

-> `res` -> (`drawable`, `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-ldpi`, `drawable-mdpi`, `raw`)

-> `AndroidManifest.xml`

So, If i want to generate `apk` file for Application1, i have to do the following:

1. `SVN` Checkout of Application Common code first.
2. Then, Application1 Content and build application to generate `apk` file.

Can i do the above two steps by using any script? The script should be in such a way that if i give the SVN directory paths and desired location, the script must automatically get the Application content from different `SVN` Directories and form the project structure in the desired location. Does anyone done this before?

Please provide your thoughts/links to achieve this?

Comment: If you have common code you should put it in a separate library project.

Comment: I cannot make the library project because drawable content varies with large amount of data(in MB Size). Making Library project is bad way of implementation for this case

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Common code should go in a library project. Resources on the application project.

Comment: `svn ls -R <URL-of-RepoDir1>` + `svn ls -R <URL-of-RepoDir2>` + `dir /S /B WC-dir-final` will help more than plain-text of description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you **share files** between Application projects - you can use file-externals and link objects inside one common repo
- If you **share** the whole **dirs**  between Application projects - you can use directory-externals and link objects inside different repos
- If you share nothing and Application project is combined data of repo1 URL+repo2 URL + ... + repoN URL you have to see at builder tools, which perform, using specs, any operations, needed for building  project ("The Right Thing for The Right Task" will be better, than glare on the knee hack): "everything is thought out before us", but you *can try* write bat-file (PowerShell etc.) with all svn export|svn cat/mkdir/mv operations